# Javascript not working in VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a requirement where when an option is selected in the picklist, one of the checkbox should be checked(whose id is PK1 in the code below). I tried executing using Javascript but somehow it's not working. Can someone help me? 
Here is the code:

```
                    <apex:outputLabel value="System"/>

                    <apex:outputPanel >

                             <apex:selectList id="sys" value="{!sys}"  size="1" onselect="checkthis()">

                                   <apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>

                                  <apex:selectOption itemvalue="1" itemLabel="1" />

                                  <apex:selectOption itemvalue="2" itemLabel="2"/>

                                   <apex:selectOption itemvalue="3" itemLabel="3"/>

                                    <apex:selectOption itemvalue="4" itemLabel="4"/>

                                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="thePageBlock"  status="status"/>
                            </apex:selectList>

                            <apex:actionStatus startText="Showing Options" id="status" />

                    </apex:outputPanel>

                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Fe" columns="2" id="pb8"

                               rendered="{!syslicense != '--None--'}">
               <apex:inputField value="{!Internal__c.Bat__c}"/>

               <apex:inputField value="{!Internal__c.Imp__c}" rendered="{!IF(syslicense =='2',false,true)}"/>

               <apex:inputField value="{!Internal__c.Bat1__c}" id="Batvis"/>

               <apex:inputField value="{!Internal__c.Mot__c}" id="PK1"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkthis() {
        if (document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.thePageBlock.pb7.syslic}') == "2") {
            document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.thePageBlock.pb8.PK1}').checked = true;
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I tried that too and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not accessing the value of the select element but instead comparing the the html object returned by `document.getElementById` with the string literal "2". Change the `if` condition to the below statement and it should work just fine. And also the the reason salesforce has provided the `$Component` is because one can directly access the vf component ID without having to reference the actual HTML id of the component.

```
if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.sys}').value == "2") {
     .....
}
```

Also remove the semi-colon after which you have added at the end of the if statement.